# Created new maven GAE project, Eclipse importing as three different projects

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

I created a new GAE project using the `appengine-skeleton-archetype` by following the steps given at [Creating App Engine applications or backend APIs using the archetypes](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven#creating_app_engine_applications_or_backend_apis_using_the_archetypes).

The layout of the project is now different than when I did the same thing 5-6 months ago: there are subsidiary `myapp-war` and `myapp-ear` sub-projects (is that the right terminology?)/sub-directories, each with their own `pom.xml` (in addition to the `pom.xml` created in the root `myapp` directory).

When I import this maven project into Eclipse (*File > Import > Maven > Existing Maven Proects* and point it at the project root directory `myapp`), it creates three different projects, titled `myapp`, `myapp-war` and `myapp-ear`.

So my questions are:

1. Is this normal/ correct/ expected?
2. I know to add my classes to `myapp-war/src/main/java`, but what about the template files? Do they go under `myapp-war/src/main/webapp`?
3. Why doesn't the `appengine-skeleton-archetype` specify the Java version (e.g., 1.7) to use? The project I created a few months back specifies `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin` in the `<plugin>` section and under `<configuration>`, `<source>` and `<target>` can be set to 1.7.

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <version>2.5.1</version>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
           <source>1.7</source>
           <target>1.7</target>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```
4. To add [RythmEngine](http://rythmengine.org/) to my project I had to add the following in my earlier project:

   ```
   <parent>
           <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
           <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
           <version>7</version>
   </parent>

   ...

   <dependency>
           <groupId>org.rythmengine</groupId>
           <artifactId>rythm-engine</artifactId>
           <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   Where does the `<parent>` go now?
5. Where do libraries like Objectify and Guava go now? In the `myapp-war/pom.xml`?

Configuration:

1. OS: Mac OS X 10.9.4
2. Eclipse: Kepler (m2e plugin 1.4)
3. GAE SDK 1.9.8